# Is ng-init truely a bad way set variable in view without controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

I am using ui-select to create a complex page with multuple views.  For those that don't know each view is loaded via ajax when a user selects a tab (or in my case a dropdown).  Views traditionally have their own controller and html templet.  Views inherrit the scope of the parent page they are on, but have their own child scope.

In my case some of our views have no controller at all.  They are so simple that we only have html pages for them.  The problem is that I would like them to be able to toggle a boolean on a configuration object on the parent page's scope, to turn off on on some control fields on the parent page.  Everything already exists, multiple pages use these views, I simply want to expand them to toggle something on the parent.

I could do this in three ways.  I could in my ui-router use the resolve method to explicitly toggle the field I want when the view is loaded, but then I have to do this in each ui-router for each page explicitly; no cool code-reuse.

I could have my ui-router load a controller, where currently I have no controller, and the controller could do this.  However, this means manually adding a controller that is mostly unneeded everywhere I use the view, and again doesn't feel like code reuse.

Or I could use ng-init to have my view's explicitly set the value I want at load time.  To me this feels cleanest and easiest, since I don't already have a controller.

However, ng-init is frowned on, and should only be used for aliasing supposedly.  Is there a cleaner approach then using the ng-init?  is it really bad to have a view without a controller (to be more exact they have the parent controller still, but that isn't reloaded when a new view is opened).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that you don't specify controller for the route doesn't change anything. The view has its own scope, so it can be manipulated with either route controller or with directives that don't have their own scope (e.g. ngInit).

The objective of well-known remark on ngInit

> The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties
>   of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should
>   use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope

is to keep you from 'html programming'. And it doesn't have too much sense because the separation of concerns is not among Angular's virtues. Angular's habit of evaluating the code from html attributes and the way how it is used by core directives prompt you to defy it even further.

Answer (score 0):

Just dont init that variables at all. ng-show="smth", ng-if="smth" works ok if 'smth' is not defined and later u change it using ng-click="smth = !smth".

Comment: but I have views that one to toggle either on or off.  so it must change when the view changes, no matter where that click is.  I could place it on the ng-click of the dropdown that changes view, but the dropdown doesn't know which view is which, so I would end up hardcoding logic about views rather then being able to add views on the fly